# Getting blobs from similar colored contours in grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I want to select the staff lines as individual blobs in either of these images:

[image]

[image]

Is this possible?

**Edit**: The regions that I want to select are shown in this image (roughly, I selected them manually):

[image]

It's ok if other blobs are getting selected too (I can filter them by their area afterwards).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can try implement something.

Comment: These images is as far as I have gone. How can I go further?

Comment: You go further by following [one](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html) of the [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)

Comment: Can you change lighting? Because threshold can isolate pieces from your images, or adaptive threshold otherwhise, see http://opencvpython.blogspot.fr/2013/05/thresholding.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's something to get you started.  I'm working on the first image you showed.  I see you included `scikit-image` as a tag, so I'm assuming you are developing in Python.  As such, I'll be using the Python wrappers to OpenCV to help us do this.  Be advised that the parameters for each step of this algorithm that I chose are particular for the first image.  You'll have to play around with the parameters to get the other image to work.

Here is what I did:

1. Read in the image and convert to grayscale via [`cv2.cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor)
2. Perform an adaptive threshold via [`cv2.adaptiveThreshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold) to best segment out the shapes from the background. They look like trains and so I'm going to call these shapes train from here on in.
3. Perform a morphological binary closing to close any gaps that resulted from the thresholding via [`cv2.morphologyEx`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#morphologyex) and I used a elliptical structuring element
4. Fill in all holes.  Basically, you can consider a hole as an area of black pixels that are surrounded by white.  A common way to do this would be to perform a flood filling operation with the seed pixel starting at the top left of the image and then inverting the results to get these holes.  Once we have these holes, we'll use this mask to index into the image from Step #3 and set these pixels to white.  I use [`cv2.floodFill`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill).  Take note that the input image is such that you remove the upper and lower rows and the leftmost and rightmost columns and you have to initialize an output image that stores the flood filled results before calling the function.
5. Find the contours in the image via [`cv2.findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours).
6. Go through each contour and filter out those that have an area that is less than a certain amount.  I use [`cv2.contourArea`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea) to help me do this.
7. For those contours that are remaining, fill in the contours with white with [`cv2.drawContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours)

---

Assuming that the first image is called `train1.png`, here's the code!

```
# Import relevant libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read in image and convert to grayscale
im1 = cv2.imread('train1.png')
im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Adaptive Threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(im1, 255,
                            adaptiveMethod=cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            thresholdType=cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
                            blockSize=21,
                            C=2)

# Morphology to close gaps
se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,15))
out = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)

# Find holes
mask = np.zeros_like(im1)
cv2.floodFill(out[1:-1,1:-1].copy(), mask, (0,0), 255)
mask = (1 - mask).astype('bool')

# Fill holes
out[mask] = 255

# Find contours
contours,_ = cv2.findContours(out.copy(),
                              cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                              cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Filter out contours with less than certain area
area = 50000
filtered_contours = [c for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) > area]

# Draw final contours
final = np.zeros_like(im1)
cv2.drawContours(final, filtered_contours, -1, 255, -1)

cv2.imshow('Shapes', final)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('train1_final.png', final)
```

This is the image I get.  It isn't perfect, but it's more than enough to get you started.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps but it won't work as well for similar images.

Comment: I ran this code and it gave me error `error: OpenCV(4.5.5) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawContours'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'contours'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol
>  - Can't parse 'contours'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol`

Comment: Thank you. I think I figured. filter() returns an iterator so I had to convert it to list before using it. I had a question. What does `# Filter out contours with less than certain area
` do? I meant if I have very small contours and I need them segmented should I do like area < threshold?

Comment: @Sulphur - Ah, I think this was running with Python 2 so the explicit conversion wasn't required. So what that statement does is that when you isolate out all of the contours, you can use `cv2.contourArea` to find the area that the contour would create if you filled in all of the pixels that the contour encloses. You only keep the contours whose areas are bigger than a threshold. You can rewrite this as a list comprehension... in fact I have edited my post to remove the `filter` call altogether and have replaced it with a list comprehension so it won't be troublesome to others.